# Mapbox: Get country of coordinates

Tags: javascript, geocoding, mapbox, reverse-geocoding

I'm using mapbox (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.0.1/) and wounder if there is a way to get the country (or city?) of a [lat, lng] pair.

Would be nice if somebody could help me out :)

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Here is a package for that: https://github.com/vkurchatkin/which-country
You can install it via npm and use in browser with `browserify`. The API is quite simple:

```
var wc = require('which-country');

console.log(wc([-100, 40])); // prints "USA"
```

Comment: ok that looks nice. but i cannot handle it to install it. there is just a description for node.js with npm, but im using symfony2 for my serverside. i have no clue how npm works and how to integrate it in my application?

Comment: Please, i need some help here!

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/geocoding/

I found this endpoint a bit back when I had to do something similar:
http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/geocode/mapbox.places-country-v1/-73.989,40.733.json?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFyaXNhZmx5bm4iLCJhIjoibG9JcmhrbyJ9.yDc_eDeDW2DeM_JVSQPp7g

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have now fixed that task with http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/#reverse
Works pretty good for me.